# Forking a child process in electron while passing on node modules from the electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to fork a child process in a BrowserWindow (nodeIntegration is enabled & contextIsolation is disabled) while passing on the node modules of the *packaged* electron application. Is there any way to do so?

Recommended by some AI, I tried to set env: { ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE: 1 } as the parameters of fork.

(full code snippet: const bot = fork('./bot.js', [], {silent: true, stdio: console.log, env: { ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE: 1 }});)